# Robust invisible watermarking algorithm for embedding a sequence of numbers in a JPG image

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, watermark, steganography

I'm looking for a watermarking algorithm which is robust to scaling (up to 0.2 of the original image size), to cropping (at some extent) and JPEG compression. It should also be fast (at least the decoding phase) because I want the decoding done in near real time.

There are many academic articles on the subject but it's hard to estimate their performance (speed).

Comment: Your question is open-ended and inviting to opinions, which isn't good for this site. It's true that most articles don't discuss speed performance, but have you tried comparing any methods yourself? Any algorithms I've used tend to finish in less than 5 seconds at most. In watermarking, where the secret length is short, your speed bottleneck may come from transforming the accomodating image, or searching for the best locations to hide the secret based on the features of the cover image.

Comment: I have tried several DCT based watermarking algorithms. They were quite fast (about 1 second for extracting the watermark), but they weren't robust enough. I will be glad if you cound point me to specific articles that implement the robustness level I mentioned above

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know any more than you regarding this. If someone were to pitch in with an idea, he'd do what you can already do; keep searching the literature. You want to also consider that your question, as currently stated, is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: DId you end up to finding good algorihtm @MustiRabin ?